# Using Average function can I round up or down in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, match, rounding, average, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet which makes calculations based on chosen criteria for a game. Visual graphs result to display ranges. This was working fine until I made a duplicate sheet '**Av Range**' which is identical to the previous '**Range**' sheet, with the exception that cells H, N, T, Z 23:25 (in yellow, orange and red) make the following average calculations:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX('Hero Range'!$B$2:$4, 0, MATCH(R23, 'Hero Range'!$B$1:$1, 0))),0)
```

So, if we take character "War Hound" for example, the range numbers returned are 3,2,3. The average is 2.67 and can be displayed as "3" via formatting the cell. However, the graph conditional formatting formula will see "2.67" and not the displayed number "3" and that poses a problem with an accurate representation.

I have marked the sheet with information on purple background to further explain. I also attach a graphic so you see what you are getting yourself in to!

Here is the full Google Sheet:
[APC Planner](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1llUPvvmxzMd9SkO99LRmyYgJj1EjjFLoXnakDHtGyK4/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Google Sheet View]

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
=ROUND(IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX('Hero Range'!$B$2:$4, 0, 
 MATCH(R23, 'Hero Range'!$B$1:$1, 0))), 0), 0)
```

or:

```
=ROUNDUP(IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX('Hero Range'!$B$2:$4, 0, 
 MATCH(R23, 'Hero Range'!$B$1:$1, 0))), 0), 0)
```

or:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX('Hero Range'!$B$2:$4, 0, 
 MATCH(R23, 'Hero Range'!$B$1:$1, 0))), 0), 0)
```